# DateTimeZone error when trying to set up Importer

Tags: solspace-importer

Importer 2.2.2 seems to have installed correctly on EE 2.7, then receiving the below error when entering setup for the Module.  Any thoughts on why the error is being thrown and how to fix it?

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone ()' in D:\Inetpub\CBLink1\system\expressionengine\third_party\importer\addon_builder\addon_builder.php:4097 Stack trace: #0 D:\Inetpub\CBLink1\system\expressionengine\third_party\importer\addon_builder\addon_builder.php(4097): DateTimeZone->__construct('') #1 D:\Inetpub\CBLink1\system\expressionengine\third_party\importer\act.importer.php(65): Addon_builder_importer->timezone_offset() #2 D:\Inetpub\CBLink1\system\expressionengine\third_party\importer\addon_builder\addon_builder.php(702): Importer_actions->__construct() #3 D:\Inetpub\CBLink1\system\expressionengine\third_party\importer\mcp.importer.php(139): Addon_builder_importer->actions() #4 D:\Inetpub\CBLink1\system\expressionengine\controllers\cp\addons_modules.php(357): Importer_mcp->index() #5 [internal function]: Addons_modules->show_module_cp() #6 D:\Inetpub\CBLink1\system\codeigniter\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(319): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #7 in D:\Inetpub\CBLink1\system\expressionengine\third_party\importer\addon_builder\addon_builder.php on line 4097

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Importer, as of this writing, is **2.2.3**. This version adds EE 2.7 compatibility. Please upgrade to this version and let us know if the issue persists.